# Influxdb merge syntax

Tags: influxdb

What's the right syntax to merge 3 or more series on influxdb?

Query below works fine for 2 series:

```
select mean(value) from "serieA" 
merge "serieB" 
where time > now ()-3m group by time(60s)
```

Tried:

```
merge "serieB" "serieC"
merge ("serieB","serieC")
merge "serieB","serieC"
merge "serieB" and "serieC"
```

**EDIT: Figured that out:**

```
select mean(value) from merge (serieA,serieB,serieC) ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use wildcards like this, with **InfluxDB <= 0.8**:

```
select mean(value) from merge(/my.series.*/) group by time(1d);
```

**NOTE:** The syntax has been deprecated since **InfluxDB 0.9**. See the [InfluxDB documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/concepts/08_vs_09/). In InfluxDB 0.9 neither the MERGE nor JOIN operations are supported.